Using itext7 .net web api
I am trying to use a font that is stored in the project in the Fonts folder, but I get an error
 PdfFont cFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("Fonts/CalibriLight.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
 PdfFont cFontI = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("Fonts/CalibriItalic.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
 PdfFont cFontB = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("Fonts/CalibriBold.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
 PdfFont cFontBI = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("Fonts/CalibriBoldItalic.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);

Error: `Error: Bad subtable format identifier: 4
I would love to use standard fonts, but I need support for special characters from other languages, that is, I need a font that supports UNICODE
`


I have already tried specifying the full path, but I get the same error

The problem turned out to be in fonts, they must contain a digital signature so that itext7 can recognize it. Pay close attention to which fonts you download
